# WSO2 password policy error when creating user in multitenancy scenario

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I'm evaluating WSO2 5.3.0 so I installed the product on premises. Inside the Super Tenant, I created a sub-tenant TA.

When Connecting to TA with the admin associated to it, I try to create users. It always fails with the error

> Could not add user PRIMARY/jfo. Error is: Password pattern policy violated. Password should contain a digit[0-9], a lower case letter[a-z], an upper case letter[A-Z], one of !@#$%&* characters

In fact it seems that this is a password policy issue because if I set "admin" as password the error is

> Could not add user PRIMARY/JFO. Error is: Password at least should have 6 characters

But it does not work even with "Admin123!" as password value for the account. and from my check :
- Password policy is not accessible (nothing is displayed) in TA when I go to Identity Provider/Resident 
- Password policy is not activated in the Super Tenant and it is validated as I can create users with the password "admin" with no issue nor warning.
- All others parameters are set to OOTB value.

Does anyone has an idea ?

Thanks

JF

Comment: I created one other tenant TB with the same process and I cannot reproduce the same behavior.

Comment: User can be created with an unsecure password and password policy can be displayed for the specific tenant.

Comment: Are you using the default LDAP user store or a JDBC user store?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it was an error at creation of my first tenant cause the Identity Provider / Persistent pane is empty on the faulty tenant. It prevents me for accessing the Password Policies pane for example.

Deleting the faulty tenant and recreating it solved the problem. I, on other hand, did not get any reason or source of the faulty creation.